# How to create json file path with variable in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write cookies to a json file.

```
cookies = web.get_cookies()
with open('test.json', 'w') as outputdata:
    json.dump(cookies, outputdata)
sleep(5)
```

Which writes cookies to test.json.

I am trying to create a cookie file for each user and each website visited such as.

```
cookies/{user}/{website}.json
```

'w' should create a file if it does not exist. But instead of the file being created I am getting error file does not exist.

I have defined the variables, printing user shows the username.

When manually creating the file such as test.json in the first example the script works.

How can I create the file at the path with variables?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'w'` does create a file **provided the containing directory exists**.

You could ensure that the directory exists with `os.makedirs`:

```
# create directories if required without error if they exist 
#  thanks to exists_ok=True
os.makedirs(f'cookies/{users}', exist_ok=True)
with os.open(f'cookies/{users}/{website}.json':
    ...
```